# Is there any way we can improve the spoiler formatting?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

The spoiler line is great for hiding text:

> If you edit this post, you can see the ways I tried to use the spoiler formatting which produced the fails.

But it can be difficult to use sometimes.

> ! Maybe I want to have multiple chunks hidden in a row
>
> ! Well nope, does not work like that

You have to include non-blocked text between two things in spoiler hiders

> That non-block text above made me exist!!!

Well that's a simple fix right?

> ! Just put all the text in one block. Put a return at the end of a line and indent the next paragraph with some spaces.
>                                  Ahhh, if only it worked that way, then that's what we would do.

But it doesn't, so we have to talk

> like

this

> .

Does anyone know why the spoilers behave this way, and is there anything we can do to make them function as blocks?

Edit: Based upon Koa's answer and ABCdexter's question, I started testing what things work in a spoiler.

> **Bold**
>  *Italic*
>  $\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: and we need better formatting in spoilers, like bullet point

Comment: Yesterday, I was using the stackexchange android app and faced [a lot of trouble using the spoilers](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33790/1766). Apparently, the **bold** and *italics* also don't work in the spoiler, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @ABcDexter I was able to put bold and italics in. Look at edit.

Comment: You might want to see [my answer here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4960/4421) for more info on using spoilers.

Comment: One comment.  Is there any way to get spoiler in the top margin of the answer box page (similiar to link / quote / code / image icons)?  That would be way helpful.

Comment: @zipzit yes, this would be a great addition. I see that it is possible for me to select a block of text and click bold and that it inserts *s in the right places. It should also be possible to create a button where you select a block of text and click spoiler. It would add ">!" to the beginning of every line and "  "(two spaces) to the end of every line.

Comment: @TonyRuth  Yes, exactly. Right now you have to remember to choose Quotation when you highlight the text, and then add the `!` to each line.  That's not intuitive at all.  A click would be SO much easier.

Comment: @zipzit It would be a feature request, but since spoilers are rarely used on most SE sites (except: Puzzling and Movies & TV) I imagine it would see little push.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spoilers totally work with multiple lines:

> Just
>  have
>  two
>
>  spaces
>  after
>  each
>  line

Also, you need to add a new `>!` at the start of every line.

`>! This shows up`
`>! as a multi line spoiler.`
`>! Like breaks`
`>! Are a double empty space`
`>!`
`>! Like that.`

> This shows up
>  as a multi line spoiler.
>  Like breaks
>  Are a double empty space
>
>  Like that.

If you need two spoilers with no text in between
`>! Do`

`<! >`
`>!this`

> Do

> this

For code blocks in spoilers
`>! Do something<pre><code>like       ...`
`>!this</code></pre>`

> Do something
>
> ```
> like       ...
> this
> ```

Aligned equations must be on one line though
`>! Like so\begin{align}f(x)&=0&\text{if }&x\neq 0\\&=1&&x=0\\\end{align}`

> Like so\begin{align}f(x)&=0&\text{if }&x\neq 0\\&=1&&x=0\\\end{align}

Comment: He's not referring to multi-lines, though, Koa.  He's looking at multi-line spoilers with a linebreak in between.  For some, odd, reason, this doesn't work and disables spoilers, entirely.  For example, a line break after "up" will break yours.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I updated it to show how to enter line breaks. Sure, not having to do it this way would be nice, but it's not the end of the world.

Comment: This is definitely useful thanks.

Comment: Note that you can also separate two spoiler blocks without putting text in between them by adding an empty HTML comment between the two blocks:  `<!-- -->`.  This results in a small amount of whitespace between the two spoiler blocks.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Could be useful to add this as "Tipp" to this [post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4894/useful-tips-tricks)

Comment: @BmyGuest I made a new [answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4960/4421).

Comment: Maybe I'm being mean, but isn't double-tapping a common knowledge across SE?

Comment: @SahibPrime Spoilers are used *way* more on Puzzling than anywhere else, and are more often used for entire paragraphs including various formatting.  In most other places, they are used for a single plain text word or phrase, so a lot of this stuff is moot.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: Can this please be added to http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help? As a new user to this site I had great difficulty getting my spoiler tags to work as I wanted them to and the help page suggested by the editor wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Separate lines with   `\n>!` like this:

```
>!Line 1  
>!Line 2  
>!Line 3
```

Note that these are:

`>!Line 1`   <------- TWO SPACES
`>!Line 2`   <------- TWO SPACES
`>!Line 3`       <---------  NO SPACES

> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to have multi-line spoilers

> with a linebreak in between them,

> you can use a blank line, a line containing just `&nbsp;`, and another blank line

Comment: Well, nope. Too bad this is not "Multi-iine Spoilers". This is just single-line spoilers separated by `\n\n \n\n`.